# eGalaxTouch P80H84 2581 stops working after a while - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, usb, keyboard, touchscreen

We changed the model of touch screen from old:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0eef:c000 D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd 

⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch EXC3188-4642-08.00.00.00  id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch EXC3188-4642-08.00.00.00 UNKNOWN  id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

to:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0eef:c002 D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd

⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H84 2581 v00_test3_m k4.10.143 UNKNOWN id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H84 2581 v00_test3_m k4.10.143 id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Now, we have the problem that touch screen suddenly stops responding to touch events and the issue is resolved if the monitor is turned on/off. I would like for some help on how to even start debugging this. Any other needed information will be added.

Answer (score 0):

According to iiyama tech support, which is using eGalaxTouch, there what a firmware update (bug) that had been shipped with some screens.

> the new Touch devices of the -3215 series have a so-called Hover functionality, i.e. the touch also works behind an additional pane of glass. In order to keep the calibration through the glass as accurate as possible, a quick calibration was programmed here, which is triggered by switching the device off and on again. If the device is not switched off for ~ 72h, a touch lock is activated to prevent problems with the hover calibration.

This update disable the touch input after 72 hours without auto touch calibration. The auto calibration is happening on controller startup, this is why it's working again after a screen power on, power off or after USB unplug/replug. This is not good for 24/7 kiosk for instance.

The solution is to do a firmware update with the latest firmware available.

For the iiyama TF3215, the informations I have are :

```
Model       S/N between     and 
TF3215-B1   11715103xxxxx   11715124xxxxx   do update FW
TF3215-B1AG 117161105xxxxx  11716122xxxxx   do update FW
```

I successfully update the firmware on a Windows 10 platform.
I'm still trying to figure out how to update how to update the firmware on Ubuntu.

There is a lot of firmware depending on touch controller and screen s/n. Your best option is asking your screen supplier for the right one.